# Hive issue: cannot acces Web UI of Hive Server 2 deployed in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2

Tags: hadoop, hive, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have successfully deployed Apache Hadoop 3.3.0 and now deploying Apache Hive 3.1.2 on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 image.
The problem is that I cannot access the Hive web UI through hiveserver 2.

I run the following commands to start required hive daemons:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service metastore &
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver2 &
```

Everything works as expected besides I cannot access the web UI of the Hive Server 2 both on 10002 and 10001 ports.

The tutorial I used is located at https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/561/apache-hive-312-installation-on-linux-guide

UPD

The server exited after generating multiple sessions

```
user@EPRUPETW09D9 ~/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin                                                                                                                                                        [17:17:41]
> $ $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver2 &
[2] 12535

user@pc ~/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin                                                                                                                                                        [17:18:04]
> $ 2021-03-30 17:18:05: Starting HiveServer2
Hive Session ID = b716abf7-28f1-4c31-8f12-ef694e1c1ee6
Hive Session ID = 2ecb9d99-8452-4310-b27d-f5aedeb7cd86
Hive Session ID = 04608448-f363-471e-807c-38aa407e340c
Hive Session ID = 3f44df14-eafc-4b3a-9275-4e7270d7ea57
Hive Session ID = 9b7e7fb3-0a41-4ab0-96e0-4a1d8114b6b2
Hive Session ID = ca319d1e-55c1-4126-bbec-e6f9f5ef7c9a


user@pc ~/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin                                                                                                                                                        [17:28:02]
> $ Hive Session ID = 0743d3b6-7664-42be-84d8-88eeb397320f
Hive Session ID = 9df5e6ef-24c9-4fb1-a9b3-35c092cad637
Hive Session ID = 536ec80c-fd72-4b04-aff3-5a8c7a6c2a99
Hive Session ID = c101a42a-f375-4f88-b3a3-806ff6d9ab7d
Hive Session ID = 1ac3cb90-086e-451d-ad0b-4a23ecc864c6
Hive Session ID = e1a0257b-800c-4874-b219-0ad7d6350516
Hive Session ID = 6163b14d-d788-48c2-838b-486547141206
Hive Session ID = 87709d05-8784-44a0-bc34-09e024fc69e7
Hive Session ID = c6703154-18cf-4483-aeae-755ea528d4ee
Hive Session ID = a40a6d8f-6b1f-4673-8351-41c5d782dd0c
Hive Session ID = 47518483-9988-4fb0-99b7-af3aa7f409d1
Hive Session ID = 5441bc12-5fa5-47d4-81d6-daac15e6bb55
Hive Session ID = ce133ccd-91f9-4354-b429-cb024c1d1d95
Hive Session ID = 374fd8bb-1172-4554-b1e9-5ce27fc1d36b
Hive Session ID = 8d2e308a-519b-474f-885e-74fe168d776c
Hive Session ID = 46bd3ddc-0796-47c1-b224-ba3478bf254c
Hive Session ID = b5730564-de3a-4095-839f-d566d1dfbc6e
Hive Session ID = 4303134f-e2c4-4d47-8864-d56fd3edb7ee


user@pc ~/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin                                                                                                                                                        [18:19:33]
> $

user@pc ~/hadoop/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin                                                                                                                                                        [18:19:33]
> $ Hive Session ID = d83ac53c-e93d-49cd-9d49-b1fc35eebb59
Hive Session ID = bab44cca-cdbb-4f7e-b6f2-c16eb4716a9a
Hive Session ID = e810c5d0-ddc8-4662-962b-22e34e0d173c
Hive Session ID = 9326d9a7-6a68-4a69-ae5e-0bb435b0de65
Hive Session ID = 8d3b74fb-f024-484a-aafa-83079a897865
Hive Session ID = 07901a44-6cd2-45b5-92af-25798add640f

[2]  + 12535 exit 255   $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --service hiveserver2
> $
```

Comment: Colleagues say that the behavior may be a result of derby usage. Trying to switch to another database for metastore.

Comment: The problem was solved using PostgreSQL database for Hive metastore service.

Answer (score 0):

Do use PostgreSQL for your metastore DB with the following settings:

```
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>hivepassword</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hiveuser</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/hivedatabase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
  </property>
```

Be cautious when adding those parameters to the `hive-site.xml`: the password param is in the default template file on ~272 line that replaces your actual password if your param is placed above the default one.

Also I suggest to consider cloudera tutorial on https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.0/hive-metastore/topics/hive-postgres.html.

Don't forget to update the `pg_hba.conf` file with the following line:

```
host    hivedatabase       hiveuser            127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

After succefull connection to the Postgres database you may experience other issues. You can check the Hive log at `/tmp/user/hive.log`.

Personally I had an issue with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and solved it with editing the `hive-site.xml` according to the following:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.active.passive.ha.enable</name>
    <value>false</value> # change false to true
</property>
```